# Incorrect syntax near при выполнении запроса

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

выполняю запрос и подставляю переменные с данными сервера и БД

```
const hostAsodu = environment.database.hostAsodu;
const databaseAsodu = environment.database.databaseAsodu;

sequelize.query(
`select  ...
 left join [:hostAsodu].:databaseAsodu.dbo.DowntimeReason ... `,
   {
       replacements: { hostAsodu, databaseAsodu },
       type: QueryTypes.SELECT,
   },
);
```

на выходе получается так

```
left join [N'DESKTOP-SERVER'].N'ASODU'.dbo.DowntimeReason
```

и при выполнении запроса вылетает ошибка `Incorrect syntax near 'ASODU'.`
я так понимаю проблема в том как передает строку в запрос, как решить эту ошибку?

Comment: `${[:hostAsodu].:databaseAsodu.dbo.DowntimeReason}`

Comment: @InDevX запрос начало подчеркивать и вылезло куча ошибок по синтаксису

Comment: вынесите в отдельную переменную и её вставляйте через ${}

Comment: @InDevX спасибо огромное вам, помогло